# Asp.Net redirecting from login page to another page dosent work

Tags: asp.net, redirect, authentication

I am using asp.net.
I have a login page.
I use this control in the login page:

```
  <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="forgotPassword" Text="Forgot Password" 
       NavigateUrl="~/Account/PasswordRecovery.aspx" >Forgot Password</asp:HyperLink>
```

When I click this Link I find myself redirected back to the login page. The address in the Browser's address bar is like this:

```
/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fPasswordRecovery.aspx
```

It does not concern the PasswordRecovery page. any other page does not work as well, even a new fresh page with nothing on it or in the code behind.

The only page that Works is About.apsx, Which was located in the project automaticlly on creation.

I tried lookin for some kind of a spaciel permision to the about page, but I cannot find any in Web.Config.

Please help me, this stuff is really wierd and I can't explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow access for this page to all users including guests. To do that, the easiest way is to create a new folder (for example "Public") and put there this page or other pages that need the same access. In this folder add a web.config with this code:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If you don't want to change the page location, you can use the "location" tag:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <!-- regular configuration -->
    </system.web>
    <location path="Account/PasswordRecovery.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: i thought about that but the About.aspx didnt have such a thing and still worked... strange..